# What does SQL Server do for spatial data outside the bounding box of the index?

Tags: sql-server, spatial-index

I read [an article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964712.aspx) that says:

> The (x-min,y-min) and (x-max,y-max)
>   coordinates determine the placement
>   and dimensions of the bounding box.
>   The space outside of the bounding box
>   is treated as a single cell that is
>   numbered 0.

I took this to mean that everything "outside" the index is actually indexed in a special place, so if I do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM GeometryTable WHERE @MyShape.STContains(GeometryColumn)
```

Where `@MyShape` is entirely outside the bounding box, it should only check things outside of the bounding box (so it still uses the index).

But later, the article says:

> Only operations computed on objects
>   that are entirely inside of the
>   bounding box benefit from the spatial
>   index.

Which seems to say the opposite -- that if `@MyShape` is outside the bounding box, it will do a full table scan.

Which is it?